# What is the continuation here if I want to open the files

Tags: shell, find, linux-mint

What needs to be added so that all the files found will be opened?

find . -iname '04*x'

Comment: checkout the `-exec` flag

Comment: I made something random but it worked: find . -iname '04*x' -exec xdg-open {} \;

Answer (score 1):

`-exec` flag is used to provide the command that has to be executed on the files found using the find command.

from the manual -

```
 -exec utility [argument ...] ;
         True if the program named utility returns a zero value as its exit status.  Optional arguments may be passed to the utility.  The expression must be terminated by a semicolon (``;'').  If you invoke
         find from a shell you may need to quote the semicolon if the shell would otherwise treat it as a control operator.  If the string ``{}'' appears anywhere in the utility name or the arguments it is
         replaced by the pathname of the current file.  Utility will be executed from the directory from which find was executed.  Utility and arguments are not subject to the further expansion of shell pat-
         terns and constructs.
```

below I am using vi editor to open the found files -

```
find . -iname '04*x' -exec vi {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below commands to open the files found by `find` command :

```
find . -iname "filename" -exec cat {} \;
find . -iname "filename" | xargs cat
```

The first command is to use `-exec`, which will give the output to `cat` command to open the files and show it on the terminal. `{}` represents the output by the `find` command.

The second command is to use `xargs`, which will give the outout to `cat` command to open the file like it did in the first option.